# Is there any difference between interface var and implementaion var in .m

Tags: objective-c

/* Variable declared in @interface of .m file */

```
@interface ClassA () {
    NSMutableArray *mDocuments;
}
```

/* Variable declared in @implementation of .m file */

```
@implementation ClassA () {
    NSMutableArray *mDocuments;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a variable in `@interface` is so it can be seen by other files, so a `public` declaration.

Declaring a variable in `@implementation` is `private` to the file.

See this thread for more in-depth: [Private ivar in @interface or @implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840884/private-ivar-in-interface-or-implementation)

Comment: Is this visible, even if I declare in `@interface` of **.m** file?

Comment: It will be visible in ClassA in either location. You should put it in `@implementation` unless you have a reason for it to be public. (In my experience, I've never declared in @interface, only in the .h file).