# public private and protected in objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, ios5

Hi I am trying to learn Opps concept in Objective C but I know PHP so I took a program in which for public, private and protected mentioned bellow.

```
<?php


//Public properties and method can be inherited and can be accessed outside the class.
//private properties and method can not be inherited and can not be accessed outside the class.
//protected properties and method can be inherited but can not be accessed outside the class.

class one
{
    var $a=20;
    private $b=30;
    protected $c=40;
}

class two extends one
{

    function disp()
    {
        print $this->c;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

$obj2=new two;
$obj2->disp();  //Inheritance
echo"<br>";

$obj1=new one;
print $obj1->c; //Outside the class

?>
```

So this I am trying to convert in Objective c code mentioned bellow.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface one : NSObject
{
@private int a;
@public int b;
@protected int c;
}
@property int a;
@property int b;
@property int c;

@end
@implementation one
@synthesize a,b,c;
int a=10;
int b=20;
int c=30;
@end

@interface two : one

-(void)setlocation;

@end

@implementation two

-(void)setlocation;
{
   // NSLog(@"%d",a);
    NSLog(@"%d",b);
   // NSLog(@"%d",c);
}

@end
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        two *newtwo;
        newtwo =[[two alloc]init];
        //calling function
        [newtwo setlocation];    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code I am getting

```
2015-11-03 23:20:16.877 Access Specifier[3562:303] 0
```

Can some one resolve my problem.

Comment: Are you compiling this for iOS or OS X?

Comment: I am compiling this in OS X Command line tool. Just want to know about public private and protected concept.

Answer (score 1):

This type of question has been asked before and there's a good explanation in the accepted answer for [Private ivar in @interface or @implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840884/private-ivar-in-interface-or-implementation)

In general I would recommend you avoid instance variables and use `@property` instead. Properties have the benefit of read-only/write controls, and free synthesized setters and getters (which if you're learning OOP concepts is a critical concept you should employ).

Properties are declared in the `@interface` part of an Obj-C file. For access control (according to the link) you have no public/private/protected keywords. All Obj-C methods (and by extension, properties) are public if they're defined in the .h file. If you want them "private" you define them in the the .m file using a class category:

```
//MyClass.m
@interface MyClass ()
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* myString;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@end
```

Comment: First of all Thanks to your reply for my query, Ok I want to Get the output value is 30 but I am getting 0 in that Coding, can you suggest me how to do that.

Comment: If you converted your ivars to properties they have a default value. `int` will default to 0, so you'll want to override your `init` constructor to set those values after your class is allocated and initialized. Do a search on stack overflow for Obj-C custom/override init, or refer to a recent Obj-C book or learning website for the nuances, as Obj-C constructor implementation is rather different from PHP's.

Comment: If you have further questions that people haven't asked before on StackOverflow, feel free to start a new question.